# btrfs, LUKS, swapfile: How to hibernate on swapfile?

Tags: linux, fedora, hibernate, btrfs, luks

I'm using btrfs encrypted by LUKS on fedora 32 silverblue, kernel version 5.7.7 with anaconda installer default setting.

Because fedora installer automatic partition does not add swap partition or file (or I've done wrong), I added swapfile on myself for hibernation like this:

```bsh
$ # swapfile under /var directory because the location is the only part user can modify on fedora silverblue
$ touch /var/swapfile
$ chattr +C /var/swapfile 
$ fallocate --length 10GiB /var/swapfile
$ sudo chown root /var/swapfile 
$ sudo chmod 600 /var/swapfile 
$ sudo mkswap /var/swapfile 
$ sudo swapon /var/swapfile
```

and I added `swapfile_t` attr for selinux:

```
$ ls -Z /var/swapfile
unconfined_u:object_r:swapfile_t:s0 /var/swapfile
```

Then I followed arch wiki instruction(https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Power_management/Suspend_and_hibernate#Hibernation_into_swap_file_on_Btrfs).

my `/var/swapfile`'s physical offset is 19793240064 and page size is 4096, so I added kernel param with grub. here's part of my `/etc/default/grub` kernel params now:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="rd.luks.uuid=luks-572bfd87-6fa7-4be1-8c73-4759ac9af3cd rhgb quiet resume=UUID=572bfd87-6fa7-4be1-8c73-4759ac9af3cd resume_offset=4832334"
```

here's my blkid:

```
$ sudo blkid
/dev/nvme0n1p1: UUID="5490-E733" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI System Partition" PARTUUID="46ecd0d1-6722-4b92-af73-9574a58eb332"
/dev/nvme0n1p2: UUID="c9294f4d-9c92-4c08-a037-715223443f2b" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="731852d5-26cd-43bb-8904-c4256247f97d"
/dev/nvme0n1p3: UUID="572bfd87-6fa7-4be1-8c73-4759ac9af3cd" TYPE="crypto_LUKS" PARTUUID="e74de89a-fe5f-402f-a3bf-e398ad069b5b"
/dev/sda: BLOCK_SIZE="512" UUID="C602B4D602B4CD25" TYPE="ntfs"
/dev/mapper/luks-572bfd87-6fa7-4be1-8c73-4759ac9af3cd: LABEL="fedora_fedora" UUID="337b2fcb-a61b-4976-89ac-2b3feee02963" UUID_SUB="932cfe1c-9713-4063-bda0-a8a792654c39" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="btrfs"
```

and hibernation failed. it seems resume parameter problem. I tried `UUID=572bfd87-6fa7-4be1-8c73-4759ac9af3cd` and `UUID=337b2fcb-a61b-4976-89ac-2b3feee02963` and both failed. What were wrong? How can I setup swapfile hibernate properly?

I've checked `journalctl -u systemd-logind` and found the message but that didn't help:

```bsh
...
 localhost.localdomain systemd-logind[936]: Failed to open swap file /var/swapfile to determine on-disk offset: Permission denied
...
```

Comment: Fedora has [changed to zram](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Fedora-33-Aims-SWAP-On-ZRAM) long time ago so it doesn't need to create a swap file. See [Hibernation without swap enabled](https://superuser.com/a/1581056/241386)

Comment: @phuclv using zram for swap is not useful for hibernation; to hibernate the swap contents must be persisted when power is removed.

Comment: I am having a similar problem on manjaro and have not posted a question as this question is very similar but unfortunately has no answers (usable or otherwise).

Comment: @RidiculousRichard did you even read the linked question above? You can use zswap which uses a real swap file/partition, or just add another swap file/partition with lower priority, or create a systemd service to handle the hibernation

Comment: Many articles on the subject with various variants. Check these more likely ones: [link1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6769/hibernate-and-resume-from-a-swap-file/1132154#1132154), [link2](https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/fedora-hibernate.html), [link3](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/t/howto-hibernate-into-swap-file/6542), [link4](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/08/how-to-use-swap-file-instead-of-swap.html), [link5](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/434177/why-cant-a-file-as-swap-be-used-for-hibernation-in-linux). Perhaps one of them will supply the missing ingredient.

Comment: @phuclv zram is RAM (which loses its contents when powered off) holding compressed data.  If you try to hibernate to zram the hibernation will 1) save data to the zram 2) remove power and the saved data and finally 3) boot as if just powered on will all your state lost.  Suspension/sleep does not remove power and is NOT hibernation.  Wrong information written in a answer is still wrong.

Comment: @harrymc I will work through your links when I have a chance.  It should be noted that the combination of LUKS encryption containing a btrfs filesystem seems to be related to the problem (I haven't checked all the links).  Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: @RidiculousRichard who tells that you can hibernate to zram? I said **zswap** which is a completely different thing. Do a research before commenting. And there's also a solution to enable swap file on hibernating if you've read the other answer

Comment: "Fedora has changed to zram long time ago so it doesn't need to create a swap file" – phuclv Aug 31 at 9:29  The question is about a swapfile not about something else all together.  Feel free to add your answer of not to have the situation but that doesn't help answer the actual question.

Comment: After all it will be relevant to some people and they will then be able to reward your effort by upvoting.

Comment: Let me add another link: [Use a swap file and enable hibernation on Arch Linux - including on a LUKS root partition](https://confluence.jaytaala.com/display/TKB/Use+a+swap+file+and+enable+hibernation+on+Arch+Linux+-+including+on+a+LUKS+root+partition).

Comment: @harrymc.  Thank you for your help; do you want to add an answer so I can assign the bounty to you?  For other readers, the secret was to use "sudo findmnt -no SOURCE,UUID -T /path/to/swapfile" and btrfs_map_physical from https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Power_management/Suspend_and_hibernate#Hibernation_into_swap_file_on_Btrfs

Comment: This was actually in my first [link1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6769/hibernate-and-resume-from-a-swap-file), so I added it to my answer as reference in addition to your link.

Comment: I think the "Permission denied" error might be caused by missing SELinux rules (that should allow systemd to access the swap file). You can verify by looking into "/var/log/audit/audit.log". See step 4) in my answer below for a workaround.

Answer (score 5):

The following steps enable hibernate to swap-file on Fedora Silverblue 33, with a btrfs filesystem, possibly encrypted with LUKS. Unfortunately it's not very straight forward, but it works.

Note that *secure boot* must be disabled for hibernation to work. Check in the BIOS settings that it's disabled.

For more background information and on why hibernation is not available out of the box, see this [old Fedora Workstation wiki page](https://web.archive.org/web/20220724195133/https://pagure.io/fedora-workstation/blob/master/f/hibernationstatus.md).

1. **Create and configure a swap-file the same size as the system memory**.

```sh
sudo touch /var/swapfile
sudo chattr +C /var/swapfile
sudo fallocate --length "$(grep MemTotal /proc/meminfo | awk '{print $2 * 1024}')" /var/swapfile
sudo chmod 600 /var/swapfile
sudo mkswap /var/swapfile
sudo swapon /var/swapfile
echo '/var/swapfile none swap sw 0 0' | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab
```

2. **Set the `resume` kernel parameters.**
   First we need to calculate the *offset* of the swap-file.
   The following command is using the `btrfs_map_physical.c` program as described in the Arch Linux [wiki page on power management](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Power_management/Suspend_and_hibernate#Hibernation_into_swap_file_on_Btrfs).

```sh
sudo podman run --rm -it --privileged -v /var/swapfile:/var/swapfile -v /tmp:/tmp debian:stable sh -c '
  apt-get update &&
  apt-get install -qy gcc wget &&
  wget "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/osandov/osandov-linux/61679ecd914d653bab14d0e752595e86b9f50513/scripts/btrfs_map_physical.c" &&
  gcc -O2 -o btrfs_map_physical btrfs_map_physical.c &&
  ./btrfs_map_physical /var/swapfile | sed -n "2p" | awk "{print \$NF}" >/tmp/swap_physical_offset
  '
SWAP_PHYSICAL_OFFSET=$(cat /tmp/swap_physical_offset)
SWAP_OFFSET=$(echo "${SWAP_PHYSICAL_OFFSET} / $(getconf PAGESIZE)" | bc)
```

Then we build the actual kernel parameters and print them to the screen.

```sh
SWAP_UUID=$(findmnt -no UUID -T /var/swapfile)
RESUME_ARGS="resume=UUID=${SWAP_UUID} resume_offset=${SWAP_OFFSET}"
echo "${RESUME_ARGS}"
```

⚠ Make sure the output looks similar to this, just with a different UUID and offset:

> resume=UUID=3d2b6777-0114-4a9d-8b98-e279e7e09cda resume_offset=7753110

If the output looks correct, set the kernel parameters with *grubby*:

```sh
sudo grubby --update-kernel=ALL --args="${RESUME_ARGS}"
```

3. **Disable systemd swap space check.**
   To avoid false positive systemd errors about the swap size, if there's already an existing swap target (e.g. the default zram device).

```sh
sudo mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/systemd-logind.service.d/
cat <<-EOF | sudo tee /etc/systemd/system/systemd-logind.service.d/override.conf
[Service]
Environment=SYSTEMD_BYPASS_HIBERNATION_MEMORY_CHECK=1
EOF
sudo mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/systemd-hibernate.service.d/
cat <<-EOF | sudo tee /etc/systemd/system/systemd-hibernate.service.d/override.conf
[Service]
Environment=SYSTEMD_BYPASS_HIBERNATION_MEMORY_CHECK=1
EOF
```

4. **SELinux: allow systemd to access the swap-file.**
   This is a workaround for missing rules in Fedora's "selinux-policy" (see [1](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1845594) and [2](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1797543)), and should be fixed in the future version 3.14.7.

```sh
cd "$(mktemp -dt)"
cat <<-EOF | tee systemd_swapfile.te
module systemd_swapfile 1.0;

require {
    type init_t;
    type swapfile_t;
    class file { open getattr read ioctl lock };
}

allow init_t swapfile_t:file { open getattr read ioctl lock };
EOF
checkmodule -M -m -o systemd_swapfile.mod systemd_swapfile.te
semodule_package -o systemd_swapfile.pp -m systemd_swapfile.mod
sudo semodule -i systemd_swapfile.pp
cd -
```

5. **Reboot and test hibernate.**
   First reboot to apply all settings:

```sh
systemctl reboot
```

Then try to hibernate:

```sh
systemctl hibernate
```

Comment: works perfectly! Tested on Fedora 33 KDE Spin, I executed `sudo grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg` because I did not executed `grubby` but modified manually `/etc/default/grub`

Comment: for me, with the above instructions, resume from hibernation yields in a black screen.

Comment: @user8162 you're running Fedora Silverblue? What version? Problems about hibernation are usually logged to the journal, e.g. check the log from the last boot: `journalctl --boot=-1`

Comment: The link to the wiki is dead.

Comment: @artfulrobot thx, updated.

Answer (score 2):

The missing step for the poster was finding the the UUID of the partition
containing the swapfile, when required to select the partition that the
swap-file resides on.
This can be retrieved using the `findmnt` command:

```
sudo findmnt -no SOURCE,UUID -T /path/to/swapfile
```

There are various methods published for hibernating on a swapfile,
each valid in its intended environment.
Below are some references, but you will find more in the comments above
on the post:

- [Hibernate and resume from a swap file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6769/hibernate-and-resume-from-a-swap-file) (method used by the poster for Arch Linux)
- [Power management/Suspend and hibernate - Hibernation into swap file on Btrfs](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Power_management/Suspend_and_hibernate#Hibernation_into_swap_file_on_Btrfs)